# AppleWatch circle progress (or radial arc progress) with images error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

I'm developing an app for Apple Watch using WatchKit and I need to implement a circular progress while recording audio, similar to Apple demos.

I don't know if WatchKit includes something to do it by default so I have created my own images (13 for 12 seconds [209 KB in total]) that I change with a timer.

This is my source code:

**Button action to start/stop recording**

```
- (IBAction)recordAction {
   NSLogPageSize();
   NSLog(@"Recording...");

   if (!isRecording) {
      NSLog(@"Start!");
      isRecording = YES;

      _timerStop = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:12.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(timerDone)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];

      _timerProgress = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(progressChange)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
   } else {
       NSLog(@"Stop :(");
       [self timerDone];
   }

}
```

**Action when timer is finished or if tap again on the button**

```
-(void) timerDone{
   NSLog(@"timerDone");
   [_timerProgress invalidate];
   _timerProgress = nil;
   [recordButtonBackground setBackgroundImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ic_playing_elipse_12_%d", 12]];
   counter = 0;
   isRecording = NO;
 }
```

**Method to change progress**

```
- (void)progressChange
{
  counter++;
   NSLog(@"%d", counter);
   NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ic_playing_elipse_12_%d", counter];
   [recordButtonBackground setBackgroundImageNamed:image];
   NSLog(image);
}
```

This is a gif showing the bug. It starts to show but change the image randomly until it gets a pair of seconds. (Note: I have already checked that the first images have the right progress)

[image: Screen recording that shows my bug]

**Update (other solution): using startAnimating**

There is a new way to show a circle progress using *startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:duration:repeatCount*

You need to specify the images range and the duration for your animation. See an example below:

```
[self.myElement startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 360) duration:myDuration repeatCount:1];
```

Comment: I have the same problem but not recording sound, so I hope somebody can help us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a side-effect of the way WatchKit interprets image names.

Image names ending in numbers are used to represent frames in an animated image, so "ic_playing_elipse_12_10" is being interpreted as the first frame of the image named "ic_playing_eclipse_12_1" and your 10th image gets displayed when you want it to display your first one.

You should be able to just change your image names so the number isn't the last part of the image name and it will fix it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your great answer (and your great sight). I have saved a lot of time trying to solve this :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is answered but I would like to explain better the solution of startAnimating.

```
[myElement startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(imageIdBegin, imageIdEnd) duration:duration repeatCount:repetitions];
```

In order to use this, you need a suite of images named like you want but with sequential ids. For example: progress_0.png, progress_1.png, progress_2.png, .., progress_n.png

You can decide the begin index and the end index using that values in NSMakeRange(imageIdBegin, imageIdEnd) just indicating the number id (not the full image name)

Of course, you will need to indicate the duration of the animation in seconds, WatchKit will interpolate for you to animate your images between init index and end index.

And finally, you can indicate if you want to repeat this animation (for example for a loading action) or not. If you don't want to repeat, you have to indicate 1.

I hope this can help more people to perform circle progress or another animations inside their AppleWatch applications :)